# pip2pi / pip downloading zip instead of targz

Tags: python, pip, pip2pi

I'm trying to use pip2pi to get python packages into a folder.

The command I am using is as follows:

```
pip2pi -N -x deps/pip/ --no-use-wheel  -r deps/ordering.txt
```

This works perfectly apart from one package, [feedparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) which pulls down a zip file.

Is there a flag I can pass to pip2pi or to pip that will only bring down targz files. I've been looking and haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks :)